# Unable to copy entire from input file to Output File in Java

Tags: java, arrays

This is the code using for file copying input file to output file.

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReadandWrite {

    public static void main(String[]  args) throws IOException {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:\\writeIntoTextFile.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("D:\\writeIntoTextFile1.txt"));
        bw.write(br.readLine());
        bw.close();
    }
}
```

The output i am getting only first line from Input file.

[image: Input file(writeIntoTextFile)]

[image: Output File(writeIntoTextFile1)]

Comment: please suggest i want use that code only i am thinking that while i can use it but getting error

Comment: `readLine` reads just one line.

Comment: You call `br.readLine()` just once. To read the entire file you have to use `br.readLine()` until `br.readLine()` returns `null`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-can-i-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java

Comment: Depending on your Java version, you might want to consider using the stream returned by `br.lines()`. It could feel much more straight forward to you to consume all the lines, one after each other instead of needing to get each line in (as suggested) a loop.

Comment: i am using java 11 and 
    public static void main(String[]  args) throws IOException {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:\\writeIntoTextFile.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("D:\\writeIntoTextFile1.txt"));
        bw.write(br.readLine());
        bw.write(br.readLine());
        bw.write(br.readLine());
        bw.write(br.readLine());
        bw.write(br.readLine());

        bw.close();
    }
}
but how can i write in reapted code in loop i am not getting logic

Comment: Hmm. All you're doing is copying a file. So why don't you just do `Files.copy`?

Answer (score 2):

`readLine()` read just one line at once.

To read all lines you have to call `readLine()` until it returns `null`

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\writeIntoTextFile.txt"));
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\writeIntoTextFile1.txt"));

try{
            
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        bw.write(line);
        bw.newLine();
    }

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

br.close();
bw.close();
```

Also there can be other option: `lines()` which returns a `Stream` of all lines: `Stream<String>`

In this case you have to deal only with writing lines, without checking when you reach the end of file.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\writeIntoTextFile.txt"));
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\writeIntoTextFile1.txt"));

br.lines().forEach(line -> {
    try{
        bw.write(line);
        bw.newLine();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});

br.close();
bw.close();
```

Comment: For completion: Since Java 10 there is a `reader.transferTo(writer)` which accepts a writer as parameter and will transfer all the content of the read file to the writer.